# How do I check the content of a Django cache with Python memcached?

Tags: python, django, memcached

Tools version:

- Python 2.6.5
- Django 1.3.1
- memcached 1.4.10
- python-memcached 1.48

Memcached is currently running:

```
$ ps -ef | grep memcache
nobody    2993     1  0 16:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u nobody -l 127.0.0.1
```

I'm using memcached and python memcached with my Django proj and I've set it like the following in `settings.py`:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'TIMEOUT': 86400,
    },
}
```

I've set the cache in the code:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.set('countries', ['Canada', 'US'])
```

I then open a Django shell to inspect the content of the cache:

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> 'countries' in cache
True
>>> import memcache
>>> mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=1)
>>> mc.get('countries')
>>>
```

When I use Django's cache, `countries` key exists.  However, when I use Python's memcache, I don't get anything for countries.  What am I doing wrong above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django prefixes cache keys with a colon. You can inspect memcached [like so](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/) if this doesn't help.

Comment: For reference django no longer prefixes its cache keys with a colon by default. You can however still make this happen by using the KEY_PREFIX configuration option described here. http://bit.ly/1lzFFPi

Comment: Why would you shorten the [Django Cache Key Prefixing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#cache-key-prefixing) URL?

Comment: I did it because I was thinking I was going to run out of comment space. ( I wont do it in the future )

Answer (score 5):

You can use memcached_stats from:
    https://github.com/dlrust/python-memcached-stats

Example:
(I used pylibmc for the cache, but I think this should be the same is you use python-memcached)

```
import pylibmc

from memcached_stats import MemcachedStats
mem = MemcachedStats() # connecting to localhost at default memcached port

# print out all your keys
mem.keys()

# say for example key[0] is 'countries', then to get the value just do
key = mem.keys()[0]

import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=1)
value = mc.get (key)
```

There is also a command line interface to memcaced_stats:
python -m memcached_stats

Have a look at the github repo as the README is very clear.

Comment: there's a bug in your code where you do mc.get() .. what is mc...? I assume its from pylibmc. +1-nd tho. the memcached-stats lib is awesome.

Comment: see docs http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/ ...typical for client instantiation...mc = pylibmc.Client(["127.0.0.1"], binary=True,behaviors={"tcp_nodelay": True,"ketama": True})

Answer (score 3):

The following script dumps all the keys of a memcached server. It's tested with Ubuntu 12.04 and a localhost memcached, so your milage may vary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'stats items'  \
| nc localhost 11211  \
| grep -oe ':[0-9]*:'  \
| grep -oe '[0-9]*'  \
| sort  \
| uniq  \
| xargs -L1 -I{} bash -c 'echo "stats cachedump {} 1000" | nc localhost 11211'
```

What it does, it goes through all the cache slabs and print 1000 keys of each.

Comment: It does not dump all the content of a memcached server. It just shows the existing keys.
It's tested with Ubuntu 16.04.