# Get list of Cache Keys in Django

Tags: python, django, memcached, django-cache, django-caching

I'm trying to understand how Django is setting keys for my views. I'm wondering if there's a way to just get all the saved keys from Memcached. something like a `cache.all()` or something. I've been trying to find the key with `cache.has_key('test')` but still can't figure out how the view keys are being named.

UPDATE: The reason I need this is because I need to manually delete parts of the cache but dont know the key values Django is setting for my cache_view key

Comment: Could you clarify why you need this? As my answer below mentions, this isn't possible inside of Django. If we know your use-case, we might be able to provide alternate solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check the content of a Django cache with Python memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512842/how-do-i-check-the-content-of-a-django-cache-with-python-memcached)

Comment: Related question: [How do I delete a cached template fragment in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778988/how-do-i-delete-a-cached-template-fragment-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/ as explained in [How do I check the content of a Django cache with Python memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512842/how-do-i-check-the-content-of-a-django-cache-with-python-memcached)

Answer (score 37):

For [RedisCache](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache) you can get all available keys with.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.keys('*')
```

Comment: 'RedisCache' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: @KaramHaj I think for newer versions you can try to use `cache.get('*')`

Comment: @KaramHaj `cache.get('*')` returns `None` instead of every keys like `cache.keys('*')`. Tested on django 3.2.3 and redis 3.5.3

Comment: This answer does not work for `RedisCache` that is provided by Django 4+ See my answer below for more details.

Comment: This answer does not work for RedisCache in Django >= 4: 'RedisCache' object has no attribute 'keys'

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned there is no way to get a list of all cache keys within django. If you're using an external cache (e.g. memcached, or database caching) you can inspect the external cache directly.

But if you want to know how to convert a django key to the one used in the backend system, django's **make_key()** function will do this.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#cache-key-transformation

```
>>> from django.core.cache import caches
>>> caches['default'].make_key('test-key')
u':1:test-key'
```

Answer (score 7):

For debugging, you can temporarily switch to [`LocMemCache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) instead of [`PyMemcacheCache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached):

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
    }
}
```

then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630237):

```
from django.core.cache.backends import locmem
print(locmem._caches)
```

Answer (score 7):

## For Redis Backend

I'm going to add this answer because I landed on this SO question searching for exactly the same question but using a different cache backend. Also with REDIS in particular if you are using the same REDIS server for multiple applications you will want to scope your cache keys with the `KEY_PREFIX` option otherwise you could end up with cache keys from another application.

My answer is for if you have setup `KEY_PREFIX` in your `settings.py` and if you are using either `redis_cache.RedisCache` or `django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache`

e.g.

```py
 CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "redis_cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": f"redis://localhost:6379",
        "KEY_PREFIX": "my_prefix",
    },
 }
```

or

```py
 CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": f"redis://localhost:6379",
        "KEY_PREFIX": "my_prefix",
    },
 }
```

### `redis_cache.RedisCache`

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import cache

cache_keys = cache.get_client(1).keys(
   f"*{settings.CACHES['default']['KEY_PREFIX']}*"
)
```

### `django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache`

> Doing some tests shows that using Django's built in RedisCache may already be scoped but in my case I'm doing it to be explicit. calling `.keys("*")` will also return keys that belong to celery tasks

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.cache import cache

cache_keys = cache._cache.get_client().keys(
    f"*{settings.CACHES['default']['KEY_PREFIX']}*"
)
```

### Bonus: Deleting all app keys

If you want to clear the cache for your specific app instead of **ALL** the keys in REDIS you'll want to using the prior technique and then call `cache.delete_many(cache_keys)` instead of `cache.clear()` as the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#django.core.caches.cache.clear) warns that using `cache.clear()` will remove ALL keys in your cache, not just the ones that are created by your app.

Answer (score 4):

In my setup with Django 3.2 there is a method to get a "raw" client for Redis which you can get the keys from.

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.get_client(1).keys()
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Note this does not work for the RedisCache backend that is provided with Django>=4. See my answer below for more details.

Comment: Works for django 2.2.12 as well

Comment: django 3.2 with redis: this answer gives "AttributeError: 'RedisCache' object has no attribute 'get_client'",  while "cache.keys('*')" works fine

Answer (score 3):

The [Memcached documentation recommends](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/ProgrammingFAQ#how-can-you-list-all-keys) that instead of listing all the cache keys, you run memcached in verbose mode and see everything that gets changed. You should start memcached like this

```
memcached -vv
```

and then it will print the keys as they get created/updated/deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use memcached_stats from: https://github.com/dlrust/python-memcached-stats. This package makes it possible to view the memcached keys from within the python environment.

Answer (score 2):

If this is not too out of date, I have had similar issue, due I have had to iterate over whole cache. I managed it, when I add something to my cache like in following pseudocode:

```
#create caches key list if not exists
if not my_cache.get("keys"):
    my_cache.set("keys", [])

#add to my cache
my_cache.set(key, value)

#add key to keys
if key not in my_cache.get("keys"):
    keys_list = my_cache.get("keys")
    keys_list.append(key)
    my_cache.set("keys", keys_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

this helps.

Ref:

https://lzone.de/blog/How-to%20Dump%20Keys%20from%20Memcache

https://github.com/dlrust/python-memcached-stats

```
import re, telnetlib, sys

key_regex = re.compile(r"ITEM (.*) \[(.*); (.*)\]")
slab_regex = re.compile(r'STAT items:(.*):number')

class MemcachedStats:

    def __init__(self, host='localhost', port='11211'):
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._client = None

    @property
    def client(self):
        if self._client is None:
            self._client = telnetlib.Telnet(self._host, self._port)
        return self._client

    def command(self, cmd):
        ' Write a command to telnet and return the response '
        self.client.write("{}\n".format(cmd).encode())
        res = self.client.read_until('END'.encode()).decode()
        return res

    def slab_ids(self):
        ' Return a list of slab ids in use '
        slab_ids =  slab_regex.findall(self.command('stats items'))
        slab_ids = list(set(slab_ids))
        return slab_ids

    def get_keys_on_slab(self, slab_id, limit=1000000):
        cmd = "stats cachedump {} {}".format(slab_id, limit)
        cmd_output = self.command(cmd)
        matches = key_regex.findall(cmd_output)
        keys = set()
        for match_line in matches:
            keys.add(match_line[0])
        return keys

    def get_all_keys(self):
        slab_ids = self.slab_ids()
        all_keys = set()
        for slab_id in slab_ids:
            all_keys.update(self.get_keys_on_slab(slab_id))
        return list(all_keys)


def main():
    m = MemcachedStats()
    print(m.get_all_keys())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all keys with `cache._cache.keys()` in reverse order for [LocMemCache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching).

For example, you set 4 cache values as shown below:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

cache.set("first_name", "John")
cache.set("last_name", "Smith", version=2)
cache.set("age", 36, version=3)
cache.set("gender", "Male")
```

Then, you can get all the keys with `cache._cache.keys()` in reverse order as shown below. *`:1:`, `:2:` or `:3:` before each key indicates **version**:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

print(cache._cache.keys())
# odict_keys([':1:gender', ':3:age', ':2:last_name', ':1:first_name'])
```

And, you can iterate all the keys as shown below:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

for key in cache._cache.keys():
    print(key)
```

Output:

```
:1:gender
:3:age
:2:last_name
:1:first_name
```

And, you can iterate all the keys with the versions as shown below:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

for key in cache._cache.keys():
    new_key = key.split(":", 2)[2]
    version = key.split(":", 2)[1]
    print(new_key, version)
```

Output:

```
gender 1
age 3
last_name 2
first_name 1
```

Lastly, you can iterate all the key's values which match the keys and versions as shown below. *[list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) is needed for `cache._cache.keys()` otherwise you get error and specifying a version is needed for [cache.delete()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.cache.delete) otherwise you cannot delete all the cache values and [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76936038/does-cache-set-use-version-1-by-default-instead-of-version-none-in-djang#76936070) of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76936038/does-cache-set-use-version-1-by-default-instead-of-version-none-in-djang) explains the default version of a cache value with `LocMemCache`:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

        # `list()` is needed
for key in list(cache._cache.keys()):
    new_key = key.split(":", 2)[2]
    version = key.split(":", 2)[1]
    print(cache.get(new_key, version=version))
```

Output:

```
Male
36
Smith
John
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.keys("foo_*")
["foo_1", "foo_2"]
```

A simple search like this will return all matched values. In databases with a large number of keys this isn't suitable method. Instead, you can use the iter_keys function that works like the keys function but uses Redis server side cursors. Calling iter_keys will return a generator that you can then iterate over efficiently.

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.iter_keys("foo_*")
<generator object algo at 0x7ffa9c2713a8>
>>> next(cache.iter_keys("foo_*"))
"foo_1"
```

https://github.com/jazzband/django-redis#scan--delete-keys-in-bulk

Answer (score -2):

There are some weird workarounds you can do to get all keys from the command line, but there is no way to do this with memcached inside of Django. See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/memcached/YyzonP9HUi0).