# How do I delete a cached template fragment in Django?

Tags: django, django-cache, python-memcached

Previously, I had set up a cached chunk of HTML in my Django template as follows.

```
{% load cache %}            
    {% cache 10000 courseTable %} <!-- Cached HTML --> {% endcache %}
```

Now, I have updated this cached content and want to refresh it. I tried changing the time to no avail:

```
{% load cache %}            
    {% cache 0 courseTable %} <!-- Updated Cached HTML --> {% endcache %}
```

In this case, the page still displays the old cached HTML.

I also tried removing the template tags associated with caching and reinserting them. However, in this case, the content just reverts to the originally cached content after I reinsert the cache template tags.

What can I do? I do not want to wait about 2 hours to reload my cache.

Comment: Wait, I can just do that with python-memcache?

Comment: How do I just empty the cache? I can afford to simply empty Memcache entirely.

Comment: There are only two hard problems in computer science...

Answer (score 15):

For Django 1.6+ and from the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#django.core.cache.utils.make_template_fragment_key) you could just generate the key of the partial you're looking for and delete it:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.core.cache.utils import make_template_fragment_key

# cache key for {% cache 500 sidebar username %} templatetag
key = make_template_fragment_key('sidebar', [username])
cache.delete(key) # invalidates cached template fragment
```

You just need to call `make_template_fragment_key` with your previously defined `courseTable` argument.

Comment: Line 4 of your code sample is not valid, I guess meant to be a comment, however it threw me off thinking I was looking at semi-pseudo-code, and couldn't get this to work. I think it's important to highlight that `[username]` really should be a list. Maybe it's just me  though :)

Answer (score 8):

If you could afford to empty memcached entirely, run [`flush_all`](http://www.mernin.com/blog/2008/10/how-to-flush-the-contents-of-a-memcached-instance/) cmd or simply

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.clear()
```

Or else you have to [generate the cache-key manually](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/templatetags/cache.py#L26). The `timeout` will not be refreshed until the key is expired.

Comment: This might make sense for some cases, but completely flushing cache is not a good alternative to selectively flush whenever possible and for the original question, django's `make_template_fragment_key` is probably a better approach

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Django 1.6, the `cache` template tag built its cache keys more-or-less in the body of the tag's definition (see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/templatetags/cache.py#L31)).  From 1.6 onward, template fragment cache keys have been built using the `django.core.cache.utils.make_template_fragment_key` function (see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/core/cache/utils.py#L10)).

In any case, you can delete a specific cached fragment by using or defining `make_template_fragment_key` to get its cache key like so:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import hashlib
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
from django.utils.http import urlquote

TEMPLATE_FRAGMENT_KEY_TEMPLATE = 'template.cache.%s.%s'


def make_template_fragment_key(fragment_name, vary_on=None):
    if vary_on is None:
        vary_on = ()
    key = ':'.join(urlquote(var) for var in vary_on)
    args = hashlib.md5(force_bytes(key))
    return TEMPLATE_FRAGMENT_KEY_TEMPLATE % (fragment_name, args.hexdigest())


def delete_cached_fragment(fragment_name, *args):
    cache.delete(make_template_fragment_key(fragment_name, args or None))


delete_cached_fragment('my_fragment', 'other', 'vary', 'args')
```

This code is directly copied from the django codebase so [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/LICENSE) license and copyright applies.