# Contents of locmem cache in Django?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-cache, django-caching

I was trying to use the locmem cache for my web application but couldn't find any documentation on how to see the contents of the cache. I mean I want to check if my keys are being set correctly in the cache. How can I list all the keys in this cache or is that even possible?

I found the question [Get list of Cache Keys in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048257/get-list-of-cache-keys-in-django?rq=1) but it's about memcache, not the locmem cache.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The thing about locmem is that it really is just a local memory storage. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/cache/backends/locmem.py), it's clear that the data is just being saved in a module-level variable, `_caches`, in that module. So you can just do

```
from django.core.cache.backends import locmem
print(locmem._caches)
```

Answer (score 0):

With [LocMemCache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching), 3 sets of code below can get the contents of the cache in Django. *[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76954493/how-to-remove-b-x80-x05-x95-x08-from-the-contents-of-the-cache-in-django) explains what results 3 sets of code below can get with `LocMemCache` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048257/get-list-of-cache-keys-in-django/76943589#76943589) explains how to get the key's values with the keys and versions using `LocMemCache`:

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

print(cache._cache) # Here
```

```py
from django.core.cache import cache

print(cache._cache.items()) # Here
```

```py
from django.core.cache.backends import locmem

print(locmem._caches) # Here
```