# Django inspect local memory cache from shell

Tags: python, django, caching

I would like to know if there is a way to inspect the content stored in the **local memory cache** from Django shell.

I found this answer: [Contents of locmem cache in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630237/contents-of-locmem-cache-in-django)

But it did not work. This is what I have tried so far:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.core.cache import caches
>>> caches.all()
[]
```

I found the wonderful plugin: [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). I can verify from the debug panel that the cache I created did exist and it has content in it.

I just want to know how to look at the cached content from Django shell.

Thanks!

---

Here is how I defined my local memory cache:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'question_cache',
        'TIMEOUT': 60 * 60,     # 60 secs * 60 mins
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 100
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking how you can inspect the cache in your running server from the shell?

Well, there's a reason why it's called the *local* memory cache. That's because it's local, in other words it's not shared between processes. There's absolutely no way to get access to it from a different process.

If you want a cache that you can access from a different process, you should use one of the other cache backends. To be honest, you should be doing that anyway; locmem is really only for development.

Comment: Good point :) I actually did read about the cache not being shared by other processes but it just didn't click. Thanks for pointing it out!