# Not caching view in Django LocMemCache

Tags: python, django, caching

I am trying to cache a class based view like so

**urls.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.conf.urls import url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/awesome-url$', cache_page(60 * 60)(TemplateView.as_view(template_name="awesome.html")), name="awesome"),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake'
    }
}
```

My hope was to have my views cached and I wanted to verify that this was happening by inspecting it with:

```
from django.core.cache.backends import locmem
print locmem._caches
>{}
```

Source: [Contents of locmem cache in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630237/contents-of-locmem-cache-in-django?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Sadly the backend is empty. So I am doubtful that the view is being cached, can anyone help?

Comment: Where are you running that command to indirect the cache?

Comment: Hi Daniel, from my shell via `./manage.py shell`

Answer (score 1):

As I said in that linked answer, the LocMem cache really is what the name describes: a *local* memory cache. It's just a global variable inside each process, which is only accessible inside that process.

There's no way for a command in the shell to access the contents of the local memory cache running in the server.

Use a different cache backend, or print the cache values from inside your views.